# PHP minus one week Sunday

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date, strtotime

I'm a newbie in both php and codeigniter.

I have a function which is used to label the x-axis of a chart of weekly sums of kilometers rode on a bicycle. It works (or is supposed to work) by counting back from today's date either zero Sundays or 1, 2, 3, etc as passed by an array.

I am using PHP Version 5.6.19, and this is my code:

In the Model:

```
    public function  week_start($date, $counter){
        $tstring = strtotime($date);
        $wknumber = ($counter + 1);
        $start =  strtotime("-$wknumber weeks sunday", $tstring);
    return array(date('M d', $start));}
```

In the Controller:

```
$datenumbers = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);
$dateResult = $this->bike_model->week_start(date("Y/m/d"), $datenumber);
```

In the view:

```
            for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++){
            echo "<text class = \"axis\" y = \"357\" x = \"";
            echo 26 + ($i*70);
            echo "\" dy = \".35em\">";
            echo $dates_for_table[$i];}
```

I have had it up for few days and it has been showing Sunday July 3 as the first number on on my [x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rflRz.png), as it should have. But today, it is Sunday and I expect it to now say Sunday July 10 as my most recent week. However, it is still showing last Sunday!

So my question is, is there a bug here or am I misunderstanding how '- one week Sunday' should work?

My goal is to have my function with zero as the argument return the most recent week start--either the current Sunday if it is Sunday or the past Sunday. I have found a workaround by adding an if else to the function checking if it is Sunday.

```
if ($tstring == strtotime('this Sunday')){
    $wknumber = $counter;}

else{
$wknumber = ($counter + 1);}
```

However, this feels clunky and I'm looking for a more elegant way. I also want to understand what went wrong with "- one week Sunday" since I thought I had understood how it was working.

Thank you!

Comment: I see your old code had `$start = (date('w', $tstring) == 0) ? $tstring : strtotime('last sunday', $tstring);` . Wasn't that solving your problem?

Comment: That code was something I tried, but it ended up giving me the current Sunday across the entire x axis. I had left that code in notes in my model to give some more thought to how to implement.

Comment: I just tried that alternate code again. Basically, the problem was it was checking if it was Sunday (yes!) and if so returning today's date for every value in the array. The only way I could think to get one week earlier on each point on the axis was the if/else statement at the bottom of the original question. I'm leaving this question open, even though my code now *appears* to be working, because I'm still not clear on exactly what the "- $i weeks Sunday" is doing exactly. Does it give you the previous Sunday on every day except Sunday, in which case it gives you the current Sunday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I did something similar using the object oriented DateTime style:

```
$startDate = new DateTime('NOW'); // can pass date string if not today

# reset start date to last Sunday or today if it is Sunday:
$startDate->sub(new DateInterval('P'.($startDate->format('w')).'D'));

# for debugging, output first Sunday:
echo $startDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . " => full date and time (check for timezone issues) \n\n";

$weeks = 8;
for ($i = 0; $i < $weeks; $i++) {
    # don't decrement first pass; sub 1 week on subsequent:
    $startDate->sub(new DateInterval('P'. (($i) ? 1 : 0) .'W'));
    echo $startDate->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
};
```

You should be able to adapt for your purpose.

If you want to get fancy, you can also use DatePeriod instead of using `sub` within a loop:

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
    $startDate,
    DateInterval::createFromDateString('-1 week'),
    7
);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code @ldg. It looks very promising for a few of my charts. However, being a newbie I don't understand the object-oriented  Date Time style . What does it mean when you say new Datetime and new DateInterval?   I had seen something like this in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) but couldn't figure it out.  I am in France now so need to go to bed, but I will see if I can wrap my brain around this in the morning. Thank you!

Comment: @Cyclist it's very similar to the procedural syle, see http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php and http://www.phptherightway.com/#date_and_time

Comment: Thank you! The PHP the Right Way site is very clearly written...I hadn't been there before, so thank you for that. And thank you for the additional idea of DatePeriod. This and your original function will be very useful as my project involves a lot of date periods.